# Как динамически можно создавать формы

Tags: python, django

Как динамически можно создавать формы в Джанго и добавлять в дальнейшем в базу данных , хотелось бы узнать примерную последовательность действий и вообще возможно ли это с помощью данной библиотеки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В джанго при сохранении данных в БД подразумевается, что ты будешь пользоваться моделями.
На основании описания твоей модели джанго создает таблицы в БД. Соответсвенно, если ты хочешь записывать произвольные данные в БД без предварительного описания моделей, то это противоречит основной концепции джанго. Но если очень хочется использовать django формы и шаблоны для организации ввода пользователей, то можно немного поизвращаться. Например как-то так

```
from django import forms
from django.db import connection


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    TYPE_MAP = {
        'str': forms.CharField(), # для примера я буду использовать только строковые и целочисленные поля
        'int': forms.IntegerField(),
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.table_name = kwargs.pop("table_name")
        self.field_list = kwargs.pop("field_list", {})
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field_definition in self.field_list.items():
            created_field = MyForm.TYPE_MAP[field_definition["type"]]
            created_field.required = field_definition.get('required', False)
            created_field.label = field_definition.get('label', "Field_Name")
            self.fields[field_name] = created_field

    def save(self):
        sql_insert_template = "insert into {} ({}) values({})"
        fields = ""
        values = ""

        for field_name, field_value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            if fields:
                fields += ','
                values += ','
            fields += field_name
            values += '"{}"'.format(field_value)  # тут по уму бы преобразовать строку, что бы не было ошибок при sql запросе, но это уже не тема этого вопроса
        complete_sql = sql_insert_template.format(self.table_name, fields, values)
        return complete_sql # для тестов сделал возврат строки sql
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql_insert_template.format(complete_sql))
```

тогда создание формы у нас должно быть с передачей всех необходимых параметров
В твоем случае field_list будет не постоянный, а ты будешь формировать его на основе введенных пользователем данных, погоды, дня недели, вообще чего только пожелаешь

```
new_form = MyForm(
    table_name="MY_TABLE", 
    field_list={
        'first_field': {'type': 'str'}, 
        'second': {'type': 'int', 'required': True, 'label': 'Возраст'}
    }
)
```

`print(new_form)` даст такой результат

```
<tr><th><label for="id_first_field">Field_Name:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="first_field" value="test_str" id="id_first_field" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_second">Возраст:</label></th><td><input type="number" name="second" value="91" id="id_second" required /></td></tr>
```

проверим как ведет себя форма при получении данных и результирующий sql

```
        new_form = MyForm(
            {'first_field': 'test_str', 'second': 121},
            table_name="MY_TABLE", 
            field_list={
                'first_field': {'type': 'str'}, 
                'second': {'type': 'int', 'required': True, 'label': 'Возраст'}
            }
        )
```

`form.is_valid()` выдаст нам `True` и `form.save()` вернет нам SQL запрос на создание записи в таблице.

```
'insert into MY_TABLE (first_field,second) values("test_str","121")'
```

так же мы сможем передавать форме значения введенные пользователем(`request.POST`), проверять валидность и сохранять в базу данных, если все данные корректны

например во `view`

```
def save_my_extraordinary_data(request):
    new_form = MyForm(
        request.POST or None,
        table_name="MY_TABLE", 
        field_list={
            'first_field': {'type': 'str'}, 
            'second': {'type': 'int', 'required': True, 'min': 100
        }
   })
   if request.POST:
       if new_form.is_valid():
           new_form.save()
           redirect('новый урл')
   render(request, "template_name.html", {'form': new_form})
```

Но надо учитывать, что придется еще обходить некоторые подводные камни:
название полей в бд могут быть зарезервированными словами в питон и по уму их тоже надо передавать отдельным полем и обрабатывать его. Так же полученные значения нужно более подробно обрабатывать(например у строк убирать двойные кавычки), а так же защититься от SQL инъекций. Так же нужно заморочиться с обработкой требуемых ограничений на поля там где это будет необходимо(например целочисленное должно быть больше 100 и меньше 200, или проверок на уникальность поля).

Если же под динамическими формами ты имел ввиду, что у тебя есть несколько моделей и тебе нужно, что бы django в зависимости от каких-то условий создавал тебе формы для той или иной модели в нужных тебе количествах, то да, тут будет достаточно просто

edit:
если ты собираешься добавлять форму по нажатию кнопки на странице то один из вариантов -

формируешь html с тем типом формы который тебе нужен, но у  формы проставляешь css класс, который не будет ее отображать на странице (например `.hidden`). И при нажатии на кнопку для создания новой формы, клонируешь ее, убираешь css класс `hidden` и добавляешь на страницу(все это делаешь либо с jQuery, либо чистый Javascript). И все у тебя новая форма для ввода данных готова.

Если тебе нужно, что бы одновременно отправлялась не одна форма а сразу несколько, то смотри в сторону formset https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets
Как вариант посмотреть как это делает админка django, создаешь две модели. у второй модели делаешь ссылку `ForeignKey` на первую. Затем в админке регистрируешь обе модели. Вторую модель как inline.
Можешь пример из документации взять https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline, потом заходишь в админку выбираешь редактирование первой модели и смотришь каким образом django формирует html и делаешь что-то подобное

Comment: спасибо да столь подробный ответ , под динамическими формами я имел ввиду , что при нажатии на кнопку добавить форму на странице , будет добавляться форма , но как я понимаю Django работает только с URL и это нужно делать на js или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: добавил обновление к ответу